# replace multiple numbers in array after meeting specific requirement

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

replace last values after meeting requirement of count 12 (from left) in a array
after meeting requirement replace all elements after last item '1' to 2.
and also suggest if anything smaller

```
var arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0];
var count = arr.reduce((t, i)=> {return t+i;}, 0);
if(count === 12){
  var startIndexToBeReplaced = arr.lastIndexOf(1) + 1;
  var arr = arr.map((element, index) => index >= startIndexToBeReplaced ? 2 : element);
}
console.log(arr);
```

result = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];
if original array is [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0] then result should be [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,2,2,2] I am looking if it can be simplified using ecmascript

Comment: can you simply show the output that you expect?

Comment: Are you just trying to replace any numbers that occur after the 12th element with a 2?

Comment: result = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], if original array is [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]; then result should be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] , I am looking if it can be simplified using ecmascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0];

const resp = arr.map((s => e => s >= 12 ? 2 : (s+=e, e))(0));

console.log(resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the list once, and if the index is greater than 11, replace the element (using `forEach` so you can modify the array in-place):

```js
const arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
arr.forEach((el, i) => {
  if (i > 11) arr[i] = 2;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use map?

```
var arr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
arr = arr.map((element, index) => index >= 12 ? 2 : element);
```